# What does the 25 Ω termination resistor do in a 0/180-degree hybrid power splitter?

Tags: rf, transformer, balun

The circuit in the picture is a 3dB power splitter using a 0/180-degree hybrid transformer/balun.

[image: A 180-degree hybrid transformer]

I see the impedance ratio of the transformer is \$ (14/10) ^2  \approx 2 \$, thus the equivalent output impedance of a 50 Ω input is 100 Ω into a differential load, or 50 Ω into two single-ended load, which makes sense.

But I don't understand the function of the 25 Ω termination resistor at the center-tap. I understand that [the center-tap of a transformer is often connected to ground to establish a common ground reference](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/461001/does-a-center-tapped-rf-balun-perform-better-than-untapped-baluns), but what does the resistor do? How do I calculate the effect of a 25 Ω resistor to the impedance at each port of this hybrid?

Comment: A link to the source of the picture will probably reveal the answer (if it isn't just there to reduce capacitive effects). It might be an impedance termination for any common mode interference coming back down the line from the balanced output on the right.

Comment: @Andyaka You're correct. I asked a stupid question - I first saw it on Wikipedia and kept thinking it as a power splitter, and I later found its source but completely missed the description of its reciprocity as a combiner and have played it on a simulation for half an hour without realizing it. I'll add my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 25 Ω resistor doesn't do anything when the hybrid is acting as a power splitter, in this case, the input is Port A and the outputs are Port B and Port C. The center-tap can be terminated with any impedance, shorted to ground, or kept as an open-circuit. Similarly, when the circuit is being driven as a power combiner with a pair of ideal 0-degree and 180-degree differential signals at Port B and Port C, 100% of the power is delivered to Port A with matched impedance, again, the resistor is not doing anything.

The resistor provides termination when (1) the hybrid is used as a power combiner, and (2) Port B and Port C are being driven by an in-phase common mode signal. When the power combiner is driven by two in-phase inputs, no power is delivered to Port A because common-mode signal is suppressed and goes to Port D, the center-tap. Because the two 50 Ω signal sources are in-phase, they are effectively identical voltage sources in parallel, two 50 Ω parallel resistors give the output impedance of 25 Ω - here, the 25 Ω resistor at the center-tap acts as a dummy load and provides impedance termination for any common-mode signal/noise presented in the differential input, ensuring power is never reflected.

Source of the circuit is *Practical Radio-frequency Handbook* by Ian Hickman.

> A hybrid can divide the input signal power between two outputs with negligible loss, each output being 3 dB down on the input. The basic hybrid circuit is shown in Figure 4.2a. If a signal is applied at port A, it will be divided equally between ports B and C whilst no power is delivered to port D (which could therefore be loaded with any termination from a short to an open circuit) as can be seen from the symmetry of the
>   circuit, given that ports B and C are both terminated in 50 Ω. The outputs at ports B and C are in antiphase and the arrangement is known as a 180° hybrid (port D is often terminated internally in 25 Ω and only ports A, B and C made available to the user).
>
> The corollary is that if two identical signals of equal amplitude but 180° out of phase are applied to ports B and C, all of the available power is combined and delivered to port A, port D again being isolated. If, however, the two identical signals were in phase, the currents in the centre tapped winding would produce no net flux on the core, so that port A is isolated and all the power is delivered to port D. If this is terminated with a 25 Ω load, then since ports B and C each supply half of the power, each will ‘see’ a 50 Ω termination.

I was looking for a suitable implementation for power splitter and first saw this picture in the [Power dividers and directional couplers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_dividers_and_directional_couplers#Hybrid_transformer) from Wikipedia with no explanation given, and I kept thinking the circuit as a power splitter and missed the explanation in the book.